# how to append a column from a csv file to another csv file without using panda?

Tags: python, csv

I want to append a column from 'b.csv' file and put it into 'a.csv' file but it only add a letter and not the whole string. I tried searching in google but there's no answer. I want to put the column under the headline "number". This is my code:

```
f = open('b.csv')
default_text = f.read()
with open('a.csv', 'r') as read_obj, \
        open('output_1.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
    for row in csv_reader:
        row.append(default_text[8])
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

This is the info in 'a.csv'

```
name,age,course,school,number
Leo,18,BSIT,STI
Rommel,23,BSIT,STI
Gaby,33,BSIT,STI
Ranel,31,BSIT,STI
```

This is the info in 'b.csv'

```
1212121
1094534
1345684
1093245
```

Comment: `default_text = f.read()` reads all the text from the file into a string.  `default_text[8]` then is just one character in this string.

Comment: oh, i see. thank you. Should i use "readlines()" for this?

Comment: use `lines = f.readlines()` then iterate `for line in lines:`

Comment: @MichHeng so like this? `f = open('b.csv')
lines = f.readlines()
with open('a.csv', 'r') as read_obj, \
        open('output_1.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
    for line in lines:
        lines.append(lines[0])
        csv_writer.writerow(line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concat rows read from both CSV file and pass it immediately to writer:

```py
import csv
from operator import concat

with open(r'a.csv') as f1, \
        open(r'b.csv') as f2, \
        open(r'output_1.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    f1_reader = csv.reader(f1)
    f2_reader = csv.reader(f2)
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(next(f1_reader))  # write column names
    writer.writerows(map(concat, f1_reader, f2_reader))
```

So we initialize [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for both CSV files and [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) for output. As  first file *(`a.csv`)* contains column names, we read it using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and pass to [`.writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) to write them into output without any modifications. Then using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) we can iterate over both readers simultaneously applying [`operator.concat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.concat) which concatenate rows returned from both reader. We can pass it directly to [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) and let it consume generator returned by `map()`.

Answer (score 1):

If only pandas cannot be used, then it's convenient to use `Table` helper from **convtools** library ([github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools)).

```py
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table
from convtools import conversion as c

(
    Table.from_csv("tmp/1.csv", header=True)
    # this step wouldn't be needed if your first file wouldn't have missing
    # "number" column
    .drop("number")
    .zip(Table.from_csv("tmp/2.csv", header=["number"]))
    .into_csv("tmp/results.csv")
)
```